# How to avoid dog-pile effect at Node.js & MongoDB & Redis stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching, redis

When some cached value is expired or new cache will be generated for any reason and we have a huge traffic at the time of no cache exists, there will be a heavy load on `MongoDB` and response time significantly increases. This is typically called **"Dog-pile effect"**. Everything works well after cache is created.

I know that it's a very common problem which applies to all web applications using a database & cache system.

What should one do to avoid dog-pile effect at a `Node.js` & `MongoDB` & `Redis` stack? What are best practices and common mistakes?

Comment: I really wonder if down voters really ever heard of something called dog-pile effect.

Answer (score 2):

One fairly proven way to keep the dogs from piling up is to keep a "lock" (e.g. in Redis) that prevents the cache populating logic from firing up more than once. The first time that the fetcher is called (for a given piece of content), the lock is acquired (for it) and set to expire (e.g. with SET ... NX EX 60). Any subsequent invocation of the fetcher for that content will fail on getting the lock thus only one dog gets to the pile.

The other thing you may want to put into place is some kind of rate limiting on the fetcher, regardless the content. That's also quite easily doable with Redis - feel free to look it up or ask another question :)

Comment: Set up a global lock in redis will make the problem more complex .If fail to get the lock,what will it do ? sleep or spin lock to check if update success or wait on some condition like Condition in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

Id just serve expired content until new content is done caching so that database wont get stampede.